# Accessing ms-settings:network-wifi from custom user interface shell

Tags: c#, windows-10

I have a windows form application that tries to display the windows 10 wifi settings panel when a button is pressed. The code is:

```
Process p;
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo;

try
{
    procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo( "ms-settings:network-wifi" );
    procStartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
    procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

    p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    p.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

    p.Start();
}
catch ( SystemException e )
{
    MessageBox.Show ( "exception: " + e.Message );
}
```

This works fine when the windows desktop is present; however, I need to run it from a custom user interface (implemented through GP), and it does not work in this environment.

The following quite similar code, which also *does not* work on windows 10, *does work* on windows 8.1:

```
Process p;
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo;

try
{
    Process wu;

    wu = new Process();
    wu.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\control.exe";
    wu.StartInfo.Arguments = " /name Microsoft.WindowsUpdate";

    wu.Start();
}
catch ( SystemException e )
{
    MessageBox.Show ( "exception: " + e.Message );
}
```

If I start windows explorer (from my forms app) before executing the code, it works (as expected).

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance